# blender game - animation of skeleton - not playing

Tags: animation

In Blender i have a model and an armature with one action. When i play the animation in blender it works but in blender game i cannot get the action playing.

The used blender version is 2.70 svn running in Linux Mint.

To narrow down and locate the problem i made a simple blender scene.
Here is what i did:

- Make model and skeleton and parent model to the created armature.
- Create action with a small animation
- in the logic editor i added this chain (Always - AND - Action: Play|Continue|Select Action)

here is a link to the blend file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91457585/animation%20test.blend

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the action actuator on the armature not the mesh object.

When an action actuator is triggered the object it is related to is the one performing the action, the action you setup has no effect on the mesh object.

Comment: Wow that did it! I even i tried that before but i guess something else was wrong as well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Indeed, it helped us a lot too, we were doing it the wrong way.